# « Tu en as eues » : accord du participe passé avec « en »

Tags: pronoms, conjugaison, interrogative

Je suis français, mais là, j'ai un doute…

Comment mettre cette phrase sous la forme interrogative et faire le bon accord ?

> Tu en as eues. (Tu as eu des nouvelles de cette personne.)

Je dirais : *En as-tu eues ?* Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Est-ce que tu en as eu ?  Est-ce que tu en as eues ?
>
> En as-tu eu ?  En as-tu eues ?

Ta question soulève le problème de l'accord du participe passé avec *en*.
Certaines grammaires  disent que le participe passé reste invariable quand le COD est le pronom *en*.
Grevisse dans le *Bon Usage* qualifie cette règle de « fort précaire ». Il dit que ceux qui l'utilisent justifient cette invariabilité en disant que *en* est ici un pronom neutre partitif signifiant « une partie de cela »  et qu'il est, « non pas objet direct du participe, mais complément déterminatif du nom *partie* (ou *quantité*) sous-entendu ». Mais qu'« en réalité l'usage est très indécis et l'accord a souvent lieu, *en* étant senti, non comme un neutre, mais comme un complément d'objet partitif dont le genre et le nombre sont ceux du nom représenté. »

Et il donne de très nombreux exemples où de très grands écrivains font l'accord.

> Ses ordres, s'il en a donnés, ne me sont pas parvenus (Stendhal)

**Note**
Certaines grammaires scolaires interdisant l'accord du participe passé dans ce cas là, il vaut mieux rester prudent dans le cadre de travaux scolaires et universitaires. Ici par contre il semble plus intéressant de diffuser tous les points de vue.

Comment: Quand l'accord devrait être audible, il n'y a pas vraiment de doute sur la situation : il n'est pas possible d'avoir une forme explicitement féminine même si *en* réfère à un groupe nominal féminin (cf. réponse)

Answer (score 2):

Quand le pronom *en* est le COD, il n'y a pas d'accord audible qui soit acceptable pour les francophones :

> *J'en ai prises, des cerises. vs J'en ai pris, des cerises.
>   *Elle en a mises, des robes. vs J'en ai mis, des robes.
>   *Stendhal en a faites, des fautes. vs Stendhal en a fait, des fautes.
>   *Vous en aurez écrites, des erreurs. vs Vous en aurez écrit, des erreurs.

Comme toujours, l'usage écrit tire partie des homophonies pour indiquer des informations qui ne sont en fait pas disponibles et on trouve des marques d'accord silencieuses dans ces contextes comme pour les adjectifs portant sur plusieurs noms tant qu'il ne s'agit pas de lire à haute voix une forme dont l'accord est audible.