# Accord du participé passé avec « en »

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

*Merci pour ce moment* de Trierweiler compte une [dizaine de fautes](http://bescherelletamere.fr/fautes-livre-trierweiler-merci-pour-ce-moment/) de français, mais la phrase suivante en fait-elle partie

> Oui, de beaux moments, j'en aurais vécu à l'Élysée.

- D'après Wikipédia, [il n'y a pas d'accord avec « en ».](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Le_participe_pass.C3.A9_est_pr.C3.A9c.C3.A9d.C3.A9_de_.C2.AB_en_.C2.BB) D'après
- Synapse, [« en » peut être considéré comme un pluriel](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/PP_EN.htm).

Auriez-vous d'autres références sur cet accord?

Comment: Ok, pour une reformulation de la question et clore celle-ci comme doublon (promis, ja'vais fait une recherche, mais pas trouvé l'autre).

Comment: [Question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/11823/358) reformulée mais je ne peux pas fermer celle-ci - @Gilles